# Iteration,concurrentModifcationException in Java

Tags: java, exception, iteration

I'm using a enhanced for loop over an ArrayList and wanted to remove some elements that contain a particular value.

When I try to do this I get the above exception. I've had a look around and it seems using a enhanced for loop while modifying the collection is a bad idea. How else would I go about this?

thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can keep a list of the items to be removed, then call removeAll after the loop has finished.

```
Vector toRemove=new Vector();
for (Object o: array){
  if(remove(o))  toRemove.add(o);
}
array.removeAll(o);
```

Comment: Two things.  You should use ArrayList instead of a Vector (you don't need the synchronization Vector provides).

Also, note that this method is slightly better/worse for different collection implementations.  ArrayList is one of them, as if you're removing a bunch of items it can repack them more in one operation rather than every time an item is removed (O(n) rather than O(n^2)).

Answer (score 3):

You should get an Iterator for the collection, walk that and call the remove() method on the iterator when you want to remove an element. Please be advised that not all Iterator implementations support remove(), it's an optional method!

```
for(Iterator it = collection.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
  Object element = it.next();
  if(.. should remove element ..)
    it.remove()
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind that this method can by quite slow for ArrayLists, though it will probably be slightly faster with some other methods due to not needing to "lookup" the items to be removed (e.g. LinkedList and Sets).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use the enhanced for loop to do this as you do not have access to the [`Iterator`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html?is-external=true) being used.  You need to use a regular for loop and remove elements of the `ArrayList` via [`Iterator.remove()`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#remove%28%29).